# NSCollectionViewItems don't reload when scrolling <OSX - Objective C>

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-sierra, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I'm new to learning Objective-C and I have a problem with `NSCollectionView` which I couldn't find any ways to resolve it.

**My problem is:**

I wrote a button event to create a `NSCollectionView` named `thoughtCollectionView` and added onto my `contentView` to display `NSCollectionViewItems`.

When I run the simulator, items look okay, but they don't reload when I scroll.

**Here's my code:**

**MainViewController.m**

```
- (void)thoughtShow{

    // Add Collection View
    thoughtCollectionView = [[ThoughtCollection alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, contentWidth, contentHeight)];
    NSCollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[NSCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    [thoughtCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    [layout setScrollDirection:NSCollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    layout.itemSize = NSMakeSize(50, 50);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20;
    layout.sectionInset = NSEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20);

    [thoughtCollectionView registerClass:ThoughtItems.self forItemWithIdentifier:@"ThoughtItems"];
    thoughtScrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, contentWidth, contentHeight)];
    thoughtScrollView.documentView = thoughtCollectionView;
    [contentView addSubview:thoughtScrollView];

    [thoughtCollectionView reloadData];
    [thoughtCollectionView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [thoughtCollectionView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
}
```

**MainViewController.h**

```
@interface MainViewController : NSViewController <NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDataSource>
@end
```

**ThoughtCollectionView.h**

```
@interface ThoughtCollection : NSCollectionView <NSCollectionViewDataSource, NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
{
    NSMutableArray * ar;
}

@end
```

**ThoughtCollectionView.m**

```
@implementation ThoughtCollection

- (NSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ThoughtItems *item = [collectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:@"ThoughtItems" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Reloading item");
    return item;
}

- (void)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayItem:(nonnull NSCollectionViewItem *)item forRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}

- (void)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingItem:(nonnull NSCollectionViewItem *)item forRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"Collection view count : %lu", [ar count]);
    return [ar count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(NSRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidMoveToWindow {

    NSLog(@"My collection View");
    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;
    ar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
        [ar addObject:@"Hello"];
    }

    [self reloadData];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [self layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
}
@end
```

**Simulator display:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSQ3I.jpg)

**Scroll:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss3PU.jpg)

> ThoughtItem.m

```
#import "ThoughtItems.h"

@interface ThoughtItems ()

@end

@implementation ThoughtItems

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setWantsLayer:YES];
    [self.view.layer setBackgroundColor:[[NSColor orangeColor] CGColor]];
}

@end
```

> ThoughtItem.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ThoughtItems : NSCollectionViewItem

@end
```

Comment: I don't see an obvious error in your code. Therefore I tried to run it but than noticed your did not include the code for `ThoughtItems`. Can you edit your question and add it? I think it might be part of the problem.

Comment: thank you! I just added my ThoughtItems code

Comment: The code is missing some more stuff to actually get an app running that displays just the collection view. But why do you embed the collection view in a scroll view? Shouldn't the CollectionView have scrolling itself? Might this be the problem that you are not scrolling within the collection view and instead scrolling a view which just contains the collection view? Can you check in the view debugger, where the frame of the collection view is after scrolling?

Comment: Could I ask what's the missing code ? ><
I used storyboard to add CollectionView before, and I saw it has scrollview then clipview then Collectionview. 
Now I do it programmatically ,but I didn't know how to use scrollview from CollectionView itself, so I added myself.

Comment: Thanks for helping me ! I found out the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that what's the problem with the CollectionItem.
I have to add an `Object` in the `ThoughtItem.xib` file, then change the `object` class name to `"ThoughtItem"`.

And I change `-(void)viewDidMoveToWindow` to a method which I can call it from MainViewController.
(or create `NSCollectionView` in the `MainViewController` is a way to solve it too)

Then all the problems are solved!